Failed to boot after boot_repair: wrong prefix
I recently had double failures with my dual boot ubuntu/windows system.  Windows is installed on SDA while ubuntu is installed on nvme0n1.  The 15 year old windows disk start showing errors and hurricane related power glitches corrupted the package manager db.  After installing both OSes, each would boot separately but I couldn't get the bootloader to recognize windows installation.  Eventually I discovered that the ubuntu install used the legacy bootloader and the windows install used uefi bootloader.
I googled this and found a reference to boot_repair which would resolve my issue so I booted into "try ubuntu" from the install usb, installed boot_repair and let it repair my installation.  That seemed to go well, but when I booted it, the boot failed with "/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found" and left me in rescue mode.  I looked around with ls and discovered the PREFIX called out i386-pc which should be x86_64-efi which does contain normal.mod.
I have saved the before and after logs from boot_repair and can upload them to pastebin if desired.
Somehow the bootloader is configured to boot a 32bit OS while boot_repair correctly configured grub for a 64bit OS.  I searched /etc/grub.d and /boot/grub for something that configures PREFIX but nothing shows up.
How can I reconfigure PREFIX correctly?  Can it be redefined from the boot rescue prompt?
One thing that comes to mind is to copy the x86_64-efi directory to i386-pc, but I suspect PREFIX will bite me elsewhere.

rebooted into grub rescue again and I don't think it's PREFIX that's the problem - it is set to (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub which I think is correct, it's the resultant path that's incorrect.

I think the i386-pc folder name is a red herring.  I found the the i386-pc path in the "before log" under "nvme0n1p2  Boot files:"        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img and again "nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub" section, line "184.128185272 = 197.706133504  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img  1"

I've tried a couple of things, first I manually entered an insmod for normal.mod in the x86_64 directory and I tried renaming the  x86_64-efi directory to i386-pc and both resulted in the error "error: invalid arch-dependent ELF magic."

If you just re-installed probably easier to correctly install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning. Conversion from MBR (if you have it) to gpt will totally erase drive, so make sure you have backups of your data. BIOS uses grub-pc, UEFI uses grub-efi-amd64. BIOS requires a bios_grub partition if gpt, UEFI requires an ESP - efi system partition and should use gpt. Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot, but Ubuntu does not, but probably should. If you have ESP partition, you can use Boot-Repair booted in UEFI mode and its advanced options to reinstall UEFI version of grub.

I was afraid that would be the answer.  But why did the ubuntu install BIOS boot in the first place, or rather, how do I ensure it used GPT when I reinstall.  I already have a full backup of my data, the only thing lost will be the time it takes to personalize the installation.

Found an ask ubuntu reply that gave good instruction, reconfigured boot drive and re-installed and now windows shows up in the boot menu.  Problem resolved, thanks for the help.
